# Webform : A partially-completed form was found. Please complete the remaining portions

Tags: webforms

Yesterday I have updated webform module from **7.x-4.0-beta3** to **7.x-4.9**.

Post to that I am getting this notification message, throughout the site :

> *A partially-completed form was found. Please complete the remaining portions*

I have also checked some threads :

https://www.drupal.org/node/2483859

https://www.drupal.org/node/2278177

When I check log entries I got this  error :

> *Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$is_draft in webform_client_form()*

Which suggest that some alteration leading this issue but unable to get any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Delete the form submission that is having problem(that is the submission id that is partially filled) in the following tables:

> webform_submitted_data
>
> webform_submission

Comment: Submission id that is partially filled in? What does that mean?

Comment: it means that submission id doesn't include the enough information to access via updated version.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me out solving my issue. in my case instead of deleting from the webform_submission table, in is_draft i replace  1  with 0